# proof by contradiction square

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Provide the following by contradiction : Either $2\cdot10^{2017} + 1983$ or $2\cdot10^{2017}+ 1984$ is not perfect square.
So to prove the theorem p -> q: have to assume p and not q are true and deduce a false statement r. I'm not sure how to go forward with this any tips ?

Comment: Your statement says one is not a perfect square for sure. Assume the contrary that both are perfect squares and try to get a contradiction.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you basically have to show that given a number $n$ and a $n+1$, they cannot both be perfect squares.

Answer (score 2):

Assume they are both squares, say $m^2$ and $n^2$ respectively. First off, we clearly have $n>1$. Then, because $n^2=m^2+1$, there are no other integers between them, and specifically, there are no squares between them. So they must be consecutive squares, meaning $n=m+1$ ($n^2$ is the "next square" after $m^2$). Thus we have both $n=m+1$ and $n^2=m^2+1$. This contradicts $n>1$.

Comment: would you use this same method and apply it to question above ?

Comment: why would you assume they are both squares ?

Comment: @rprogramr Because the negation of "at least one of them is not a square" is "they are both squares". We want to prove the former by contradiction, so we assume the latter, and derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Because of $$2\cdot 10^{2017}+1983\equiv 3\mod 4$$ the first number cannot be a perfect square.

But an argument probably better hitting the intent of the question : The two numbers are consecutive and the only pair of consecutive squares is $(0,1)$

Comment: would this be proof by contradiction ?

Comment: @rprogramr Yes, because we assume that we have two positive consecutive perfect squares, which is impossible.